# "Unread" filter for inbox doesn't work

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

I have 9 "old" unread messages, but the "Unread" filter doesn't show any of them. *New* ones do get shown if there are any, but not old ones. I could go to the "full inbox" view and manually search through its many pages, but that's not practical.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you confirm on "all" notifications that there are no 9 new comments under the same post, which will be squashed into a single (buggy) notification?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, I'm sure that's not it. This was btw also brought up four months ago [at meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385467/691385) and three months ago a moderator said it's a known issue, but they haven't responded anymore.

Comment: Fighting the inbox is now part of the daily SO experience.